# Fetching sharepoint list items using URL or form using javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-online

While developing React webpart, I want to add property pane value, where I can fetch the SharePoint list item using `https://sample.sharepoint.com/sites/Dev/Lists/emp/AllItems.aspx`

Using such URL. How can I do this?

was thinking with JS function: where I can achieve something like this.

https://sample.sharepoint.com/sites/Dev/_api/Web/lists/getbytitle('emp')/items`

https://sample.sharepoint.com/sites/Dev/Lists/emp/AllItems.aspx

From the above link, I want to form another URL reading values and passing to another.

Like I want to read first part https://sample.sharepoint.com/sites/Dev
and then want to read emp and the value in this URL.

expected URL:
`https://sample.sharepoint.com/sites/Dev/_api/Web/lists/getbytitle('emp')/items`

Comment: Suppose you're talking about SPFx solution, there is https://sharepoint.github.io/sp-dev-fx-property-controls/controls/PropertyFieldListPicker/ you could use, so user could configure the list data source.

Comment: @Lee_MSFT yeah but i want it this way

Comment: You could try to use PropertyPaneTextField or PropertyPaneLink to configure the url and split based on Lists to get web url and list title.